# Django admin Ordering

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Django and I am trying to order Comments using Array..

I have this class inside models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
     line_combination = models.ForeignKey(LineCombination, null=False, blank=False, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True , blank=True)
     email = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True , blank=True)
     comment = models.TextField()

     class Meta:
         ordering = ['line_combination__line__name']
```

for Line Combination I have this class:

```
class LineCombination(models.Model):
      line = models.ForeignKey(Line, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      combinations = models.ManyToManyField(GenoType, blank=False)

      class Meta:
         # Ordering the names of line Alphabetically
         ordering = ['line__name']
```

for the GenoType I have this class:

```
class GenoType(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
```

I want to make ordering in the **class Comment** By **line_combination.combinations.name** Like this:

```
ordering = ['line_combination__line__name' , 'line_combination__combinations__name']
```

but **line_combination.combinations.name** is Array So i can't put it as value ..

so how can I do it?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

One `LineCombination` has many `GenoType`s, so, we have to determine which row from `GenoType`s should be used for `LineCombination` sorting if we don't want to receive duplicates in results.

You can determine this row manually:

```
class LineCombination(models.Model):
      line = models.ForeignKey(Line, null=False, blank=False)
      combinations = models.ManyToManyField(GenoType)
      main_combination = models.ForeignKey(GenoType, null=True, blank=True)
```

And then `ordering = ['line_combination__main_combination__name']`.

In this case you have to add some logic to fill the `main_combination` field, for example in forms or in [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed).

Or you can [select this row when run queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Min
Comment.objects \
    .annotate(main_name=Min('line_combination__combinations__name')) \
    .order_by('main_name')
```